# How to programmatically find out if the console supports certain escape sequences?

Tags: java, c, console-application

Console ANSI escape sequences, e.g. for coloring, are a nice feature. However, if unsupported, I'd rather spare the user from seeing things like `[1;31mBlah Blah[0m`. Therefore, my question: Is there a way to programmatically determine whether the console supports ANSI escape, or at least have a 'good guess'? I'm especially interested in a Java solution, but the same in C would be helpful, too.

Comment: Search for the `terminfo` program. You can query that. Btw: What have you searched for yourself until now? Show us your research, so we don't have to repeat that. In your case, there are plenty of resources on the web that handle this issue.

Comment: Thank you for the hint to `terminfo`. There indeed are many resources on the web about console escape sequences, also libraries for handling this. But I didn't find a readily available solution to the problem described. If you believe I haven't searched thoroughly enough, forgive me. I've tried my best.

Comment: Check the TERM environment variable.